# Error when creating stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm noob at stored procedures, I have created a stored procedure that take some parameters from C# page, then send back result as `OUTPUT` parameter.

I need to do some calculation to get end date, so I end up using a lot of IF statements. However, when I create the stored procedure I get error that I didn't know how to solve, every thing seems correct!.

Here is the stored procedure code:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_RenewSubscription 
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @Reference nvarchar(100),
        @SubscribtionID nvarchar(100),
        @Months int,
        @Result nvarchar(200) OUTPUT
    AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @EndDate as nvarchar;
    DECLARE @MonthCounts as int;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Reference] FROM [Norton].[dbo].[SubscriptionStatus] WHERE [Reference] = @Reference)
    SET @Result = '0: Reference ID not found'
    ELSE
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Reference] FROM [Norton].[dbo].[SubscriptionStatus] WHERE [Reference] = @Reference AND [SubscribtionID] = @SubscribtionID)
    SET @Result = '0: Subscribtion ID not found'
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        SELECT TOP 1 @EndDate = [EndDate], @MonthCounts = [SubscriptionMonthCount] FROM [Norton].[dbo].[SubscriptionStatus] WHERE [Reference] = @Reference AND [SubscribtionID] = @SubscribtionID
        IF @EndDate = '0'
        BEGIN 
        UPDATE [Norton].[dbo].[SubscriptionStatus]
        SET [SubscriptionMonthCount] = @Months + @MonthCounts
        WHERE [Reference] = @Reference AND [SubscribtionID] = @SubscribtionID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
        UPDATE [Norton].[dbo].[SubscriptionStatus]
        SET [SubscriptionMonthCount] = @Months
        WHERE [Reference] = @Reference AND [SubscribtionID] = @SubscribtionID
        END

    SET @Result = '1: Done Successfully'
    END
GO

END
GO
```

This is error I got:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_RenewSubscription, Line 44
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.*

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `go` from before the end of the procedure.

ie

```
       END 

    SET @Result = '1: Done Successfully' 
    END 
GO  --- <-- get rid of this

END
```

Comment: Indeed. @Yasser, it's worth noting that [GO is not actually a SQL statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx). It's used to *separate* SQL statements, and is interpreted by the client tools, not the server. Basically, when you run the page of SQL there in Management Studio, etc., the client breaks the SQL into batches at the GO statements, and sends each batch separately to the server to be run, one after the other. Therefore, having a GO anywhere in between a BEGIN and END pair of a SQL statement will cause you a problem.

Comment: Thanks podiluska for your answer, it fix the error but I got another one, near the first ELSE, fortunately, the code in Gidil answer worked.
Thank you Matt for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_renewsubscription 
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
  @Reference      NVARCHAR(100), 
  @SubscribtionID NVARCHAR(100), 
  @Months         INT, 
  @Result         NVARCHAR(200) output 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from 
      -- interfering with SELECT statements. 
      SET nocount ON; 

      DECLARE @EndDate AS NVARCHAR; 
      DECLARE @MonthCounts AS INT; 

      IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [reference] 
                    FROM   [Norton].[dbo].[subscriptionstatus] 
                    WHERE  [reference] = @Reference) 
        SET @Result = '0: Reference ID not found' 
      ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [reference] 
                    FROM   [Norton].[dbo].[subscriptionstatus] 
                    WHERE  [reference] = @Reference 
                           AND [subscribtionid] = @SubscribtionID) 
        SET @Result = '0: Subscribtion ID not found' 
      ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT TOP 1 @EndDate = [enddate], 
                         @MonthCounts = [subscriptionmonthcount] 
            FROM   [Norton].[dbo].[subscriptionstatus] 
            WHERE  [reference] = @Reference 
                   AND [subscribtionid] = @SubscribtionID 

            IF @EndDate = '0' 
              UPDATE [Norton].[dbo].[subscriptionstatus] 
              SET    [subscriptionmonthcount] = @Months + @MonthCounts 
              WHERE  [reference] = @Reference 
                     AND [subscribtionid] = @SubscribtionID 
            ELSE 
              UPDATE [Norton].[dbo].[subscriptionstatus] 
              SET    [subscriptionmonthcount] = @Months 
              WHERE  [reference] = @Reference 
                     AND [subscribtionid] = @SubscribtionID 

            SET @Result = '1: Done Successfully' 
        END 
  END 

GO
```